# Can the default date range on the Events page be changed?

Tags: events, modern

I have a site owner who would like to display the next year's worth of events rather than the default of the next month.  Is it possible to change this range so that it defaults to a different timespan?  This is a modern site in SharePoint Online.

[image: screenshot of event page's interface indicating the default date range]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in setting to change this default behavior. Users can only manually adjust the date range each time if they want to view events beyond the one-month period.

As a workaround see: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-events-web-part-change-default-view/m-p/3719987

Add a quick link above or below the web part with a modified URL from 'Events.aspx'

Let me know if this helps.